The Holy Geeta or God Talks with Arjuna?
Which Gita should one read, The Holy Geeta by Swami Chinmayananda or God Talks with Arjuna: The Bhagavad Gita by Paramhansa Yogananda?
God Talks with Arjuna is much more detailed but for some reason The Holy Geeta is much more well known.
Also, I’ve read a few pages of God Talks with Arjuna and on thing feels weird is how the author calls Brahman as ‘Spirit’. What is the difference between them and what should one get?

I would suggest you to ask your guru. Do as guru says. As we have multiple versions of Geeta bhashya or geeta interpretation.

As per my knowledge, below is best and easy to read and understand for normal person also.
Bhagavad Gita As It Is  (Hardcover, AC Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada).
Link to the digital version:
https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/

I have read it and found it to be extremely biased towards a particular sect. Most are a little biased but they don't mistranslate the verses like this one, for this reason I would recommend you to not recommend this version to anyone who wants to read the book for the teachings. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can read what ever appeals to your psychological temperament. However, its best to know the history. Gita is one such volume within the Great Mahabharatam, first extracted by Adi Shankara who integrated it with primary Upanishads and Brahma Sutras. He gave a Bhyasa (interlinked commentary) for these 3.
If people think its ok to read Gita as is without reading at least the main chapters of Mahabharatam (Like Dhrona, Karna, Bhishma ....), OR If they choose to read it without the evolutionary connection to the Vedic link, like the way Adi Shankara first intended, then its an individual responsibility towards their own Spiritual Upliftment.
A Yogi will explore Gita in a Yogic sense, A bhakta will do the same, so will a Gyani, a Western translator, or any spinoff who tried to write Gita in their own way after Adi Shankara, it's up to the prime responsibility of the Reader.
IIT Kanpur has created a portal called GITA SUPERSITE, they collected various commentaries and translations, in various languages, with word-2-word translations. Here is the link

You better read as many versions of Bhagavat Gita as possible so that you not only get deeper insight but also grasp the difference of opinions among translators while handling every sloka. You better try to read at least two versions.
Your question Also, I’ve read a few pages of God Talks with Arjuna and on thing feels weird is how the author calls Brahman as ‘Spirit’. What is the difference between them and what should one get?
English language lacks vacabulary for Sanskrit words. Most of the translators uses spirit for Ātman/Brahman(The Absolute) and soul for Jīva/Jīvatman.
Good Luck!
